# --vanlla: Rscript: command not found when running in AWS Lambda

Tags: python, r, amazon-web-services, lambda, subprocess

I have created a lambda function which gets triggered when any R script file gets uploaded on S3 bucket.

**test.R code:**

```
a <- 1
b <- 3
c <- a + b 
data = 1:20
print(data)
```

**lambda function code:**

```
import subprocess
import json
import urllib.parse
import boto3

print('Loading function')

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    s3 = boto3.client('s3')
    bucket_name = event['Records'][0]['s3']['bucket']['name']
    key = urllib.parse.unquote_plus(event['Records'][0]['s3']['object']['key'], encoding='utf-8')

    message = "Hey file is got uploaded " + key + " to this bucket " +  bucket_name
    print(message)
    
    #3 - Fetch the file from S3
    response = s3.get_object(Bucket=bucket_name, Key=key)
    text = response["Body"].read().decode()
    print(text)
    
    command = "Rscript"
    arg = "--vanlla"
    path2script = key
    
    retcode = subprocess.call([command, arg, path2script], shell=True)
```

Trigger is working fine but its giving **--vanlla: Rscript: command not found** error. but when I run simple python script to run R script code, its working fine. Not working with AWS lambda.

Need help in this.

Comment: In your script you have `--vanlla` instead of `--vanilla`

Comment: yeah. i was trying something and removed i from it. I have tested with --vanilla also and its giving the same error. --vanilla: Rscript: command not found

Comment: Have you installed R with your Lambda code?

Comment: No. How can I install R for AWS lambda? Please guide me.